# Why my array didn't change original value after a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def prefix_sum_inplace0(arr_in):
    n = len(arr_in)
    arr_in = [0] + arr_in
    arr_in.pop()
    for i in range (1, n):
        arr_in[i] = arr_in[i - 1] + arr_in[i]
    return arr_in
arr1 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 7, 6, 11]
print("pre_sum_inplace0:",prefix_sum_inplace0(arr1),"original arr:",arr1)
```

explaining: I want to calculate the exclusive prefix sum of array,

for example if original array is `[1,2,3,4]`, so the exclusive sum of array is `[0,1,3,6]`,

I don't know why the original array didn't change because this function didn't return a new array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change some method about adding and deleting elements and it did work.

```
def prefix_sum_inplace0(arr_in):
    arr_in.insert(0, 0)
    del arr_in[-1]
    n = len(arr_in)
    for i in range (1, n):
        arr_in[i] = arr_in[i - 1] + arr_in[i]
    return arr_in
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, When you performed "arr_in = [0] + arr_in" it performed an initialization. You can see by using "hex(id(arr_in))" the address of the list changed. Use insert(0,0) instead. It'll not change the address of the list means initialization not performed.

```
def prefix_sum_inplace0(arr_in):
    n = len(arr_in)
    arr_in.insert(0,0)
    arr_in.pop()
    for i in range (1, n):
        arr_in[i] = arr_in[i - 1] + arr_in[i]
    return arr_in
arr1 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 7, 6, 11]
print("pre_sum_inplace0:",prefix_sum_inplace0(arr1),"original arr:",arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A new list is created when you do `arr_in = [0] + arr_in`. I added a few print commands so you can see the list's id change. arr_in isn't modified before the addition of [0] at the beginning, so arr1 stays the same.

```py
def prefix_sum_inplace0(arr_in):
    print(id(arr_in))
    n = len(arr_in)
    arr_in = [0] + arr_in
    print(id(arr_in))
    arr_in.pop()
    for i in range (1, n):
        arr_in[i] = arr_in[i - 1] + arr_in[i]
    return arr_in
arr1 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 7, 6, 11]
print(id(arr1))
print("pre_sum_inplace0:",prefix_sum_inplace0(arr1),"original arr:",arr1)
```